# Meaning of 'looking quite blue with the cold of his drive' and 'Ah-kishes'

Tags: meaning, poetry

> 'Twas General Janus, the first to arrive,
>
> In snow-shoes and gaiters,
>
> Escorted by skaters,
>
> And looking quite blue with the cold of his drive,
>
> See him come in, with his footman Aquarius,
>
> Who presents his Ah-kishes,
>
> That's to say, his best wishes,
>
> A choice of fresh colds, and compliments various.

This is part of the nursery poem from [Walter Crane's book](https://archive.org/details/Crane1/page/n83/mode/2up).

I have two questions from this.

1. Does 'looking quite blue with the cold of his drive' mean, 'looking pale because he got a cold from the drive'?
2. Then does 'Ah-kishes' express the sound of coughing?

Answer (score 1):

I'd take the first to mean looking pale because he was cold, as a result of walking in the snow.

I'd guess that Ah-kish is meant to be the sound of a sneeze, but it isn't the usual phrase (we say "Atishoo" for the sound of a sneeze, and don't really have a word for the sound of a cough, except "cough")

Comment: In extreme cold, people's lips, fingers, etc, can become blue.

Comment: James K is correct that an "ah-kish" is a sneeze, not a cough. There are many ways to spell a sneeze in English, but it's usually something like "atishoo". (We usually spell a cough as "ahem".) Note that the poem immediately explains the ah-kish ("that is to say...") which suggests it's a nonce word, an invention to amuse the reader.